# Multiple monitors not working VMware 16 Player

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I want to use my Windows VM with multiple monitors (with Windows as host OS). I am using the VMware Workstation 16 Player.

While in full screen mode there is the option to *Choose a monitor layout* (see screenshot). That would be exactly what I want, but clicking any layout has no effect. Unity mode is working well, but not always what I need.

[image: Screenshot of the 'Choose a monitor layour' dropdown menu]

I played around with the *Display* settings in the virtual machine settings e.g. specifying the monitor settings directly. I have not tried to use a different guest OS, I want it to work for windows. There was no setting inside the guest OS to enable more monitors or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Workaround:

Go to *File -> Preferences*

[image: Screenshot of the Player dropdown menu to navigate to preferences]

and select *Light* as your color theme.

[image: Screenshot of selected Light color theme]

You should now be able to use the *Choose a monitor layout* menu as expected.

I tested this workaround on different machines and it worked both times. Also switching back to *Dark* or *System* (in case your Host is using dark mode) for the color theme keeps your monitor layout settings, but you're stuck with that setting then.

---

I found this workaround thanks to this (hard to find) [answer by JGrover on the vmware community website](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/quot-Cycle-Through-Multiple-Monitor-quot-broken-for-triple/m-p/2864585/highlight/true#M37387).

Comment: On version of VMWare 17.0.2 - confirming that this is still a problem and for whatever reason this answer worked. I don't get it. I have no idea how a color theme has anything to do with the number of monitors selected. You would think VMWare would document this problem.